# parse HTML with Regex

Tags: c#, wpf, regex

I have Bing html and i want to parse the results from it with :

```
    string BingRegex = "<div class=\"sb_tlst\"><h3><a href=\"(.*?)\"";
    string[] results = Regex.Matches(responseStr, BingRegex).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

I get the results to the array but it add the pattern to each result , something like :

```
<div class=\"sb_tlst\"><h3><a href=\"www.cnn.com\"
<div class=\"sb_tlst\"><h3><a href=\"www.google.com\"
<div class=\"sb_tlst\"><h3><a href=\"www.gmail.com\"
```

Any idea how can i fix this and get only the url?

Comment: You shouldn't use regex to parse html.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: well you can, but it will go wrong on you quickly.

Comment: Questions like this come up every so often and the response is often the same... don't! Try using something like the HTML Agility pack http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from doing this with an HTML parser (which is a better idea), replace:

```
Select(m => m.Value)
```

with:

```
Select(m => m.Value.Groups[1].Value)
```

Although you'll probably want to throw in a little error handling to check that the group is actually populated.

But the best solution is not to use Regex or an HTML parser, but instead use the [Bing search API](http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search) because this is exactly what it's for.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest not to use regex to parse HTML. Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c). Then just use XPath to get the value of attribute you need.

The XPath for your sample div

```
<div class="sb_tlst">
    <h3>
        <a href="www.gmail.com"/>
    </h3>
</div>
```

would be

```
/div[@class='sb_tlst']/h3/a/@href
```